# How do I add new layout width options in Wordpress editor?

Tags: theme-development, themes

How can I add new custom widths to the block alignment menu?

I have set the two inbuilt ones in my `theme.json`, but how do I add more? Eg. `narrowSize` etc.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "layout": {
            "contentSize": "1200px",
            "wideSize": "1920px"
        }
    }
}
```